# Average of Relative Error (Relative Error of a Sequence)

Tags: sequences-and-series, average, standard-error

I have a sequence of ground truth and a sequence of measured values.

```
Ground truth sequence:        4,5,3
Measured values sequence:     5,4,5
```

I would like to calculate the relative error of the whole sequence. In other words, I am interested in how much different the Measured sequence is from Ground truth sequence.

Currently, I am taking the average of individual relative errors as follows:

$$ \frac{  \frac{|4-5|}{4} + \frac{|5-4|}{5} + \frac{|3-5|}{3}} {3}$$

I don't know if it is the correct way. Can someone please guide me the best way to compute it?